# Como pegar request Header passando o Authorization Bearer usando DataSnap

Tags: delphi, autenticação, datasnap, token

Estou usando `Delphi XE7`, tenho um `WebService REST` feito a partir do projeto do `DataSnap REST`, preciso pegar o `bearer-token` passado via `Header` pelo cliente, só que o `DataSnap REST` por padrão ele executa como `Basic`.

Pelo que eu pude observar ele executa o `DoParseAuthentication` da classe `TIdCustomHTTPServer`, mas a função é privada.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer, já passaram pelo mesmo problema, como resolver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O DataSnap é baseado nos componentes [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx). Quando há uma requisição `Http` com autenticação, a função `TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoParseAuthentication` é chamada. Se não houver nenhuma função associada ao `OnParseAuthentication`, ele vai tentar fazer uma autenticação do tipo `Basic`. Então para fazer autenticação com `bearer-token` eu faço da forma descrita abaixo.

Procure pela declaração:

```
  FServer := TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.Create(Self);
```

No caso, quando criamos usando o Wizard do DataSnap Rest e escolhendo a opção `standalone`, essa declaração acima fica no form criado como exemplo.

Logo abaixo dela, adicione o seguinte código:

```
  FServer.OnParseAuthentication := DoParseAuthentication;
```

A procedure `DoParseAuthentication` pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
procedure TForm1.DoParseAuthentication(AContext: TIdContext; const AAuthType, AAuthData: String; var VUsername, VPassword: String; var VHandled: Boolean);
begin
    VHandled := AAuthType.Equals('Bearer') and IsTokenValid(AAuthData);
end;
```

`IsTokenValid` é uma função que você deve implementar. Se a autenticação estiver correta `VHandled` deve retornar `True`.

**Obs.:** Eu utilizo `LifeCycle` do tipo `Invocation`

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!